# Why does to_date in my view output date in a different format than to_date in Rails console for the same object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

In my view, I do this:

```
  <td><%= client.last_contact.to_date %></td>
```

That outputs this:

```
2011-08-11
```

But when I do it in the console, I get the format I want:

```
1.9.3p194 :093 > c.last_contact
 => Thu, 11 Aug 2011 00:00:00 UTC +00:00 
1.9.3p194 :094 > c.last_contact.to_date
 => Thu, 11 Aug 2011
```

In my view, I want it to display the day and the format that it does in the console.

How do I achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to display time/date in rails views is using I18n localization feature. 
You can set datetime  formats in your `config/locales` directory in yaml file. Something like this

```
# config/locales/datetime.en.yml
en:
  time:
    formats:
      # Use the strftime parameters for formats.
      # When no format has been given, it uses default.
      # You can provide other formats here if you like!
      default: "%d.%m.%Y"
      short: "%d %b"
      long: "%d %B %Y"
      date: "%a, %d %b %Y"
```

Then use `l` helper in your views

```
<%= l client.last_contact, :format => :date %>
```

- Rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats
- Possible formats: https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en.yml
- Datetime in ruby: http://www.dzone.com/snippets/date-time-format-ruby

Comment: I tried this and am now getting an error: `I18n::MissingTranslationData in Home#index`. `translation missing: en.time.formats.date` around the line: `95:       <td><%= l client.last_contact, :format => :date %></td>`.

I copied the entire contents of that `en.yml` file (your second link) to `config/locales/datetime.en.yml`.

I checked `application.rb`, but it seems I only need to initialize/specify the locale if it is something other than English - which mine isn't. So what am I missing here?

Comment: You need to set locale in `application.rb`, change first line of yml-locale file to this locale, and everything should work well.

Comment: In my `application.rb` you mean like this:     `config.i18n.default_locale = :en`?

Then in my `yml-locale` file, have the first line be: `en:`?

Comment: Because I tried that and it doesn't work. Still getting the error.

Comment: Try to change `date` in yml-file to `time`. In second string I mean.

Comment: The thing is, I never copied your code, I copied the code here - https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en.yml. That has the entire file, and it has a time attribute there. So I have two files: `config/locales/en.yml` and `config/locales/datetime.en.yml` and both look like https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en.yml

Comment: Oh, I see. Then just add `date: "%a, %d %b %Y"` to proper section `en.time.formats`

Answer (score 5):

The console calls `inspect` on values whereas erb tags call `to_s` on their value.

While you could call `inspect` in your view, I'd encourage you to either use `strftime` which allows you to define precisely what you want

```
Date::today.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y')`
```

or use the `I18n.localize` helper (aliased to `l`) which allows you to define formats and reuse them

```
I18n.localize Date::today, :format => :long
```

Comment: Thanks...this is a nice solution, but I want to go with the I8n version. Btw, I voted you up because you explained the reasoning to me.